# How can I calculate the monthly total return for the S&P500 (SPX) stock?

Tags: stocks, rate-of-return, standard-and-poors-500

I look at the monthly returns for SPX here: [Morningstar](http://performance.morningstar.com/Performance/index-c/performance-return.action?t=SPX)

```
            January     February    March   April     May   June 
    2019    7.87        2.97        1.79    3.93    -6.58   6.89
```

Now, given the following data from AlphaVantage for April:

```
2019-04-30  
1. open          2848.6299
2. high          2949.5200
3. low           2848.6299
4. close         2945.8301
5. volume   69,604,840,000
```

I calculate for Rate of Return:

```
RoR = ((2945.8301-2848.6299)/2,848.63) * 100 = 3.41%
```

This is different from the 3.93% we get from Morningstar.

Apparently they use Total Returns or Trailing Total Returns, I am not sure.

To calculate that, I think I would need the interest, capital gains, dividends and distributions.

Is there a way for me to calculate this return using data from AlphaVantage? Or should I go a different way?

Thank you

Comment: Does Morningstar include dividend reinvestment?

Comment: I have no idea. I just know that ycharts has the same data: https://ycharts.com/indicators/sp_500_monthly_return

Comment: Of course, YCharts might just be copying MS, or vice versa, or they might both be copying some other company's numbers.

Comment: OK, so you would think that those nunbers take the dividends into account and that could explain the difference with the RoR?

Comment: It might; I don't *know*.  (That's why this is a comment, not an answer.)

Comment: Thank you, I will see if I can find this information

Comment: Apparently ycharts do not include dividends "Notes: S&P 500 monthly return not including dividends."

Comment: No dividends involved.  See my answer.

Comment: Try looking at ticker ^SP500TR on Yahoo. It is the total return index, i.e. what the S&P index should have been, taking dividends into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Morningstar, the monthly returns for SPX were:

```
        January     February    March   April    May    June 
2019    7.87        2.97        1.79    3.93    -6.58   6.89
```

The problem is that you either have bad data from AlphaVantage or   your data query from AlphaVantage was incorrect.

Monthly return is not calculated from the opening price of this month but from the closing price from the last day of the previous month.

When I used the closing price of the previous month, I got the identical numbers as Morningstar:

```
 Jun 28          2,941.76     6.89%

 May 31          2,752.06    -6.58%

 Apr 30          2,945.83     3.93%

 Mar 29          2,834.40     1.79%

 Feb 28          2,784.49     2.97%

 Jan 31          2,704.10     7.87%

 Dec 31          2,506.85
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I if calculate the RoR between the closing value of 2019-03-29 (2,834.40) and the closing value of 2019-04-30 (2,945.83) that works: (2,945.83-2,834.40)/2,834.40